# How to replace the master branch using another - with git and source tree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I often want to make the current branch the master branch, like  [described in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763006/change-the-current-branch-to-master-in-git). I use the approach that Jefromi answered.

I wonder how I can do exactly this with source tree?

Comment: Is there a reason not to do it using the git command directly like in [the answer to the linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2763118)?

Comment: @Hasturkun: convenience. I can't keep the commands in my head.

Answer (score -1):

When your in the branch you want to copy the master branch to, run this command:

```
git merge master
```

you can read about what it does [here](https://blog.sourcetreeapp.com/2012/08/21/merge-or-rebase/)

Comment: I don't think that's what the question is. Asker isn't asking how to copy/merge the master branch to another, but rather how to replace the master branch using another.

Comment: @Hasturkun: Yes, you are right. I edited the subject so that it's clearer

Comment: How about deleting the brach and then create a new one and checkout from the master branch. Is there any reason you would want to keep the commits of the branch?

Answer (score -1):

Well Jefromi's answer is perfect to [keep the content in branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763006/change-the-current-branch-to-master-in-git)
. But, I wonder why we try to make our current branch as master branch at any stage. Best practice says, Well plan your project and never make direct changes in master. Always, **Master** changes are merged into the **branch** and then branch is **pushed to master**.

Comment: This is not the question. In the world there are situations where other practises are used