# Mark a local branch as origin/master

Tags: git

I had a git repo in a computer which no longer is available, and I have a local branch which I want to be the new origin/master.  I read [Make the current git branch a master branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763006/change-the-current-branch-to-master-in-git).  It involves merging the master and local branches, but I don't have access to master anymore.  Is there any way to make my local branch the master one?

Comment: So is there any remote repository left at all?

Comment: There are 2, but they are copies of each other

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the master branch is not available anymore you can just create the master branch from your local one and use that one:

`git checkout -b master`

After, if you want to use this branch as master, you can push it to the server:

`git push -f`

This server you may have to link as a remote.

Answer (score 0):

You should push as follows:

```
git push --force --set-upstream origin local_name_of_branch:master
```

Comment: Maybe I am doing something wrong, but after running the command, has problems resolving the host name (because the host does not exist)

Comment: @JorgeKageyama , you have not setup an origin ? ?

Comment: @JorgeKageyama not to mention that you say that you want it to become the new `origin/master` ... that's foo without an origin.