# How to do a merge in git without picking up any changes?

Tags: git, merge

In the following git scenario:

```
A -- B1 -- B2 -- B3
  \- C1 -- C2 -- C3
```

I would like to merge C into B, producing another revision D, such that there are NO changes between B3 and D.  In other words, the result is:

```
A -- B1 -- B2 -- B3 -- D
  \- C1 -- C2 -- C3 -/
```

and D is identical to B3.

Using `git merge --strategy-option ours` doesn't quite do the right thing: it resolves conflicts in favor of B, but still merges non-conflicting changes.

Comment: Out of curiosity what's the point of merging C back if you aren't going to pull in any changes from that branch?

Comment: Oh wait, I guess if C is master and B is a different branch that you want to be master then this would make sense.

Comment: @BenLindsay: All the commits from C have also been cherrypicked into B at one point or another.  For reasons that are not obvious to me, this merge still results in a bunch of changes to B... which are certainly bogus, but I do want to merge it to indicate that all the changes are in B as well, and not pick up any new changes in the process.

Comment: What you're asking doesn't make sense. Either C and B are identical working copies, in which case D would be an empty merge commit, or C and B are not identical working copies, in which case D will obviously be a non-empty commit.

Comment: Why don't you compare C and B? `git difftool --dir-diff B..C`

Comment: @mkasberg: Sorry, diagram is not detailed enough.  There is in reality mutliple linear commits B1, B2, ... and C1, C2, ....  All C commits also appear as a B commit, in the same order (but not necessarily sequentially).

Comment: OK, I see what you mean. Let me rephrase my previous statement then. Either all changes from C are already in B, in which case D would be an empty merge commit, or all changes from C are not in B in which case D would be a non-empty commit. Are you sure you didn't miss anything while cherry-picking C into B? Did you look at what changes are actually happening when you do the merge? One way to see them would be to `git diff B3..HEAD` after making the merge commit (which you can always throw away if you don't like it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jefromi's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2763118/2680824) should help. Basically, assuming the `master` branch points to `C` and `better_branch` points to `B`, this should work:

```
git checkout better_branch
git merge --strategy=ours master    # keep the content of this branch, but record a merge
git checkout master
git merge better_branch             # fast-forward master up to the merge
```

Comment: This looks good, but I'm not sure it has the intended result.  `git merge --strategy=ours` only uses `ours` for conflicts, not for all changes.

Comment: Not true--see the "ours" option under the Merge Strategies section of the [git-merge documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge). It says "This resolves any number of heads, but the resulting tree of the merge is always that of the current branch head". I just tried it to double-check. For example, doing the merge will get rid of a file that has been added on the branch you want to ignore, where there wouldn't be any expected conflicts in a normal merge.

Answer (score 2):

I would use

```
git commit-tree B^{tree} -p B -p C -m "Merge from C but accept no changes"
```

This prints a commit, which you can fast-forward merge.

The `commit-tree` says "create a commit whose tree is identical to what is currently in B.  Its parents are the current values of B and C." You can then fast- forward this commit into either B or C.