# How to get the difference between the working sets (not commits) of two git branches

Tags: git, branch, git-diff

I have the following two branches that differ in files

**master**

```
 |_ document.txt
 |_ document_two.txt
 |_ document_three.txt
```

**development**

```
 |_ document.txt
 |_ document_two.txt
 |_ document_three.txt
 |_ virus.exe // want to get rid of that
```

And these are the `git log` results of both (*from top to bottom*)

**master**

```
commit: fdsdfsf1342re5252423425242234 (master, development)
add document one

commit: 563523523g233g5232sdfawe22434 (master, development)
add document two

commit: 56652u747241523g52352fsdfawew (master, development)
add document three
```

**development**

```
commit: fdsdfsf1342re5252423425242234 (master, development)
add document one

commit: 563523523g233g5232sdfawe22434 (master, development)
add document two

commit: 1213421g233g5232s41dfawe22434 (development)
ADD VIRUS.EXE ! XXX

commit: 5423345652u7433g52352fsdf1223 (development)
change document three completly

commit: 56652u747241523g52352fsdfawew (master, development)
add document three
```

### Goal

I want to clean up the **development** branch so it has all the sourcefile states of master **and** has the `virus.exe` file removed.

I already found ways to have the **master** state overwrite the **development** file states.

*Read here*: [Make the current Git branch a master branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763006/make-the-current-git-branch-a-master-branch)

But I also want to get rid of files that do not exist within the working set of **master**. In this example this would be the file `virus.exe`. Just creating a new *development* branch of the master is not an option because it is important to leave the **development** branch as an *orphan*. When overwriting/branching the **development** branch by/off the **master** branch it will lose the *orphan* state since it will adapt the whole history of **master**

*Does anybody know a way to:*

- get the differences between two branches in files? *not their commit diffs*
- removing all found differences in files by a final commit (to keep history intact) ?

*Edit*:
I found the command to give me the difference in files:

```
$ git diff-tree -r --name-status --diff-filter=A master..development
A       virus.exe
```

Is there an elegant way to directly use the output to remove from the development-branch? I would kinda use it in:

```
git checkout development && git rm virus.exe && git commit -m "clean development" && git push origin
```

Comment: If you really have a virus file in your repo, then you're probably going to want to remove it _everywhere_, not just in some commit, then push.  Lookup filter branch for more information.

Comment: No there is no virus. It is just a example meant to be "funny"

Comment: :-O you gave me the Big-O face

Comment: `git checkout development && git reset --hard master` ?

Comment: What you're providing in as `git log` output, isn't what it appears to be.  Whatever you think you're trying to do here, tossing out word salad like "working set" and falsified command output isn't the right way to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Branches don't have working sets.  (Well, maybe they do, since you have not defined *working set*, but Git does not define working set either.  But since I don't know what you mean, I'm using *working set* as an alias for *work-tree*, which *is* well-defined, and branches don't have work-trees.)

What branch names do is select one particular commit.  That commit then has some parent commit (or more than one if it is a merge); the parent has its own parent, and so on, forming a chain of commits.  As a result we can say that a branch (or branch name) *contains* some set of commits: these are the commits that are *reachable from* the name.  For a good introduction to all of this, see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).

Each commit has a stored *tree* or snapshot.  As you have found, `git diff-tree` is the so-called *plumbing command* (script-able work-horse) for comparing two trees as found in two commits:

```
git diff-tree -r commit1 commit2
```

compares the entire trees, recursively (`-r`), comparing all the files contained in the two snapshots.  You can spell this `commit1..commit2`: it means exactly the same thing, use `commit1` as the left side and `commit2` as the right side in the comparison.  The output of this comparison is essentially a sequence of instructions, e.g., *add some lines to this file, remove some lines from that one, and you'll cause the tree attached to `commit1` to match the tree attached to `commit2`.*

You can add options like `--name-only` or `--name-status`, and `--find-renames` with an optional *similarity index* value—a percentage—to have Git compute places where renaming, then changing, a file produces a shorter instruction sequence than the simpler *remove file A, and create new file B from scratch with these contents*.  For instance, perhaps the shorter sequence is *rename A to B, then remove line 17,* which is clearly much shorter than *remove file A, then create file B with these 10,000 lines: [very long list of lines]*.

The front-end, user-oriented `git diff` command in effect runs `git diff-tree` or `git diff-index` or whatever, but with the user's configuration (`diff.renames` and `diff.renameLimit` for instance) in mind, and with output sent through a *pager*, colorized, and so on.  Git calls these commands *porcelain* as they are supposed to be user-friendly (vs the plumbing, hidden behind the walls, out of sight).

When you make a *new* commit, you have Git store a new snapshot.  Git builds the new snapshot from whatever Git has in its *index* at the time you run `git commit`.  The new commit's *parent* is the old tip of the current branch; the new commit *becomes* the tip of the current branch.  This is how branches grow.

The various commands you use, such as `git rm` or `git add`, operate on the *index*.  You use `git checkout branch` to extract the tip commit of a branch into this index.  The files stored *in* the index are hard to see—you can get a complete listing with `git ls-files --stage`, but that's rarely very useful.  These files, in the index and (eventually) frozen into a commit, are in a special Git-only form anyway.  So to *work with* those files, when you have Git extract the tip commit, you also have Git extract all the files into a *work-tree*.

The work-tree has those files in their ordinary format, where you, and your computer, can work with them in ordinary ways.  But everything you do in this work-tree is really aimed at fussing with the index, because it's the index that contains what goes in the *next* commit.  Running `git commit` packages up (freezes) the index contents into a snapshot, and adds that as the new tip of the branch.

Hence, if you compare two commits (with `git diff` or `git diff-tree`), then make some changes to your index and make a new commit, what you are doing is changing your index and using it to make a new commit.  The comparison of the two commits is up to you.  Note that you can also compare any one commit *to* your index, using `git diff --cached` (porcelain) or `git diff-index --cached` (plumbing).  And, you can compare index vs work-tree, or a commit vs work-tree, also using these commands.