# Trying to implement both changes from master

Tags: github

I am new to using GitHub to manage my projects, and I've decided to take up the challenge with a partner.

The question that I have, is that we work on the same branch, being `master`.

If my teammate makes changes to the branch and I've also made changes, how do I implement my changes to the `master` branch without losing my progress and keeping their progress?

I'm hoping there is a much more elegant solution than just copying my changes, implementing theirs into my local repo, then pasting my changes and committing again.

Comment: GitHub is not git. 1) Consider creating other branches 2) `origin/master` and `master` can differ, just merge the remote into yours before pushing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make the current Git branch a master branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763006/make-the-current-git-branch-a-master-branch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working both on master(/ or `main` for new GitHub repositories), you can simply use `git push`

If it fails (because your teammates have pushed on master too), I would do a simple git pull, provided you have [Git 2.6+ and the global setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209750/6309):

```
git config --global pull.rebase true
git config --global rebase.autoStash true
```

That way, you are rebasing (replaying) your local commits done on your local `master` on top of the updated `origin/master`.
Once any merge conflict is resolved, and your program tested, you can push again.

Ideally though, your teammates would split their contribution across several branches instead of always pushing to `master`, which allows for an easier more stable workflow.