# how to make a git branch the master branch?

Tags: git

Trying to get a branch I created after working in a detached HEAD for a while, to be my master branch, but concerned that I may use the wrong sequence of actions and mess up my repo (local and remote)...

Series of actions (in "fork", a git GUI) resulting in the status shown in the image below:

- commit tagged "v0.56.4 release" pushed to remote
- did some changes and messed up my code. Stashed the changed files and checked out the previous commit to "revert" to a clean code
- continued development from there on, regularly committing and pushing changes to remote, only mildly bothered by the "detached HEAD" warning I was getting, as all the literature told me this would be an easy fix.
- commit tagged "v0.57 release 1" followed by creating a new branch called "tmp".

How do I make this "tmp" branch my new "master" branch, leaving the "stash@{0}" changes as a dead branch I have no intention to revisit?

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772192/how-can-i-reconcile-detached-head-with-master-origin) appears to provide close to the solution I am looking for, except that it doesn't mention any stashing of anything, so I am not sure what potential conflict/issue could result from following its sequence of actions.

[image: current repo situation]

Comment: Do you literally want to make `tmp` into the new `master`, regardless what `master` was before (and discarding it), or do you want to integrate `tmp` into the existing `master`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make the current Git branch a master branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763006/make-the-current-git-branch-a-master-branch)

Comment: The latter. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of the stash entry run (assuming the image is correct and it is the latest one):

```
git stash drop
```

---

Reconciling branches `tmp` and `master` can be done in many ways. Branches in Git are just stickers that you stick to commits to keep track of which is which.

You can just remove `master` and create a new sticker on the current `tmp`.
Assuming you're on `tmp` right now:

```
git branch -d master
git checkout -b master
```

Or you can unstick `master` and move it to `tmp`:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard tmp
```

Or you can use the merge mechanism and merge the changes from `tmp` to `master`. `master` is an ancestor of `tmp` so merge can be fast-forwarded which again just ends up in moving the branch label:

```
git checkout master
git merge --ff-only tmp
```

There are probably tons of other ways.
The point is: don't worry, you didn't corrupted your repository until you've lost some commit you wanted to keep, and even then it's probably still recoverable because Git doesn't garbage-collect unused things immediately.

---

The last thing to do is to remove `tmp`. (Do it after making sure the `master` is there already.)

```
git branch -d tmp
```

Comment: Thanks. I followed: git branch -d master//
git checkout -b master//git branch -d tmp and pushing all this to my remote.

Answer (score -1):

Important: copy the local repository to a backup folder before proceeding.

These commands will update the master branch to be the same as tmp branch, and delete the tmp branch:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git rebase tmp
$ git branch -d tmp
```

And these will create a branch for the stashed files:

```
$ git checkout -b stash_branch
$ git stash pop
$ git commit -m "stash commit"
```

---

Here is the procedure for master branch update, in a sample repo (mine is named `main` instead of `master`):

```
~ $ mkdir x && cd $_
~/x $ git init .
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/teixeira/x/.git/

~/x $ touch a && git add . && git commit -m "a"
~/x $ git checkout -b tmp
~/x $ ls
a
~/x $ touch b && git add . && git commit -m "b"
~/x $ touch c && git add . && git commit -m "c"
~/x $ git log --oneline
6c566d0 (HEAD -> tmp) c
f6c9cfa b
20a3d76 (main) a

~/x $ git checkout main
Switched to branch 'main'
~/x $ git rebase tmp
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/main.
~/x $ git log --oneline
6c566d0 (HEAD -> main, tmp) c
f6c9cfa b
20a3d76 a

~/x $ git branch -d tmp
Deleted branch tmp (was 6c566d0).
~/x $ git log --oneline
6c566d0 (HEAD -> main) c
f6c9cfa b
20a3d76 a
```