# Go back one commit that was pushed to remote

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I accidently pushed something that I shouldn't have and now I want to revert it, but I can't because if I do reset hard to 05669, it doesn't let me to push it because the remote HEAD is ahead...

[image]

I read on other questions that doing a forced push will cause trouble for others, but that's also what they recommend (huh?), should I really do a force push to fix this? is there another way that won't cause trouble for others?

[Git: permanently remove few commits from remote branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293531/git-permanently-remove-few-commits-from-remote-branch)

[How do I push amended commit to the remote Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253055/how-do-i-push-amended-commit-to-the-remote-git-repo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the remote branch is used by other team members, especially if it's the main development branch, then `git reset` is dangerous because it removes a commit that other people have already pulled. Also you need to do a `git push --force` which means you need to have the permission to do so.

The safest option is to revert the commit using the [git revert command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert).

This will keep your existing commits, and then will add an extra revert commit on top. This is safe because you're not changing history, or removing commits already pulled and relied on by other team members. Note that if things get out of hand during reverting (e.g., you get a conflict that you're not sure how to resolve) you can always abort the operation by `git revert --abort`.

Comment: If i'm at `762ab` and press the revert in tortoisegit, I don't see anything to revert to, only if I were to make uncommited changes they will show up...

Comment: Also, no one has pulled anything yet.

Comment: Oh nvm, there's another revert in the log, it worked great. Thanks.