# How do I revert a commit only locally?

Tags: git

I want to revert a commit that was made by someone else.  But I want the revert to be undone when I pull from remote next time. Meaning I don't even want it to be in the history when I pull and push next time. How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to permanently remove few commits from remote branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293531/how-to-permanently-remove-few-commits-from-remote-branch)

Comment: Do you want to vanish this commit only on your local machine, or do you want to remove it completely on the remote repo too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `git revert` on the commit you want to revert. Then before you do a pull, do a `git reset --hard HEAD~1` assuming you're ahead of your remote tracking branch by one commit and that commit is the revert.

Answer (score 0):

On the latest version of the repo, use `git log` to find commit and then `git checkout [COMMIT ID]`

Similar question was asked here with a great answer: [How to revert Git repository to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-to-revert-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit?answertab=votes#tab-top)