# GitLab, Terraform, and String Interpolation

Tags: gitlab, terraform

I want to use a GitLab Runner to deploy to AWS with Terraform. I have setup AWS credentials in GitLab "Variables" (`AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`). I must be misunderstanding how `.gitlab-cy.yml` performs string interpolation because I cannot get the credentials to populate.

The stage in question looks like this:

```
validate:
  stage: validate
  dependencies:
    - lint
    - unit
  image:
    name: hashicorp/terraform:light
    entrypoint:
      - "/usr/bin/env"
      - "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
      - "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}"
      - "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}"
  before_script:
    - rm -rf terraform/test/.terraform
    - terraform --version
    - terraform init -input=false -backend-config="access_key=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}" -backend-config="secret_key=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}" terraform/test
  script:
    - terraform validate
```

The pipeline fails without fail on the `terraform init` command. However, just to confirm I'm not crazy, I did try a pipeline run with the credentials hardcoded and it worked (I also immediately learned about how to permanently [delete commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49648127/how-to-completely-remove-a-commit-from-gitlab) and pipelines).

From the [relevant GitLab documentation on variable usage](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/where_variables_can_be_used.html#execution-shell-environment), I don't see anything obviously wrong.

Error message:

```
Initializing the backend...
 Error: error using credentials to get account ID: error calling sts:GetCallerIdentity: InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid.
```

Comment: The problem turned out to be Protected Branches. If you "protect" a Variable, then the variable is not available to branches that are not designated Protected.

Comment: I am pretty sure you should not be setting up environment variables in a Docker entrypoint.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Fair enough, but do you have a recommended alternative? I was working from these examples: https://medium.com/@me.daniel.meier/handling-aws-with-terraform-and-gitlab-ci-ed83d17e018e https://medium.com/@dbourgeois23/manage-terraform-with-gitlab-ci-5c24005eb62a

Comment: Have you tried the `environment` Gitlab key instead?

Comment: I'm not seeing any difference from what I've done here https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/