# Create a new branch from an existing git commit in bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a repository containing branch1.

It has two commits 123weew (current) and gwehhj12(previous).
I want to move branch1 to the previous commit and create a new branch2 at existing 123weew commit id.

How can this be done?

At worse, I just want to delete commit 123weew so that I can start fresh.

Comment: No the question is different. I want to move my branch to previous commit

Comment: This effectively accomplishes what you want to do. You can take your previous commit id of `gwehhj12` for branch `branch1` and simply do `git branch branch2 gwehhj12`. This will make the branch `branch2` from `branch1` at commit `gwehhj12`. If you want to completely discard your commit on `branch1`, which isn't recommended, you can look at the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293531/how-to-permanently-remove-few-commits-from-remote-branch I highly discourage this, however, due to possible issues you could run into when working with teams.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this in two steps. First, create the new branch at the current commit you're at:

`git branch branch2` - this creates the new branch.

`git reset --hard HEAD~1` - this resets the branch you're on (still `branch1`) to the commit before, resetting all files to the state of your previous commit.