# How to remove one specific merge from dev from git

Tags: git, azure-devops

I have a situation, where some pull-request is released on dev branch by mistake.
I want now only that pull-request (merge commit) to remove from origin/dev
Here is the picture: [image]

So, commit with a number `89e231f1`
Branch name is called: `dev`

I tired to get one commit earl;ier and to create separate branch, then to merge all other commits to that branch, but somehow it takes also a commit from this merge `89e231f1`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to permanently remove few commits from remote branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293531/how-to-permanently-remove-few-commits-from-remote-branch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [interactive rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) and remove this commit. Trigger rebase by doing:

```
git rebase -i 89e231f1^
```

Delete the merge commit by removing lines corresponding to it.

If you don't want to force push, you can revert the commit instead:

```
git revert -m 1 89e231f1
git push -u origin dev
```

This will add an another commit reverting all the changes.

Comment: thanks! then should I have all commits that have been added after `89e231f1` ?

Comment: Yes, retain all commits outside of that merge commit

Comment: just a question, it opens git-rebase-todo https://i.imgur.com/tiebxwn.png Im not really sure what to do, I need all of these commits.

Comment: when I close the file, I have 12 changes to pull and 7 changes (correct changes) to push. So if I pull, I will again get those changes that I dont want. How to avoid pull command? (I cant push before pull) https://i.imgur.com/Fzqkk40.png 
Obviously, I'm doing it locally, and for some reason it tells me that are 12 changes to be pulled.

Comment: Whenever you change the commit history, you can't do a normal push. You need to do a force push instead. If you don't want that you can revert the commit in the dev branch instead (updated the answer)

Comment: Pushing a rebased dev branch will put it the expected state, but has some bad impacts on anyone that has working changes on the existing commit history?