# How to delete all the commits I have made to a repository and to permanently delete a Git repository

Tags: github, repository, git-commit

I was brought on board as a contractor to do some work on a forked open source repository. After finishing the work and a successful launch, the hirer is ghosting me and refuses to compensate me as agreed. How can I either: permanently delete the repository without the option to restore (I still have access to Git as the owner and I'm the only one who pushed commits) or permanently delete all my pushed commits from history.

Side question: If a site is deployed on Cloudflare off a specific branch and I delete the repository, what happens? I'm assuming the webpage stays deployed based off whatever was compiled last.

Answer (score 2):

In the setting of the repo scroll down to bottom you will get the danger zone. There you can  archive or delete the repo. for detailed guide visit https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/deleting-a-repository

Comment: Thank you for your response! It's possible to restore a deleted repo though: Some deleted repositories can be restored within 90 days of deletion. For more information, see "Restoring a deleted repository." Maybe I should be trying to figure out how to permanently remove the commits I have made from history instead.

Comment: Okay I would suggest you to check these answers out. I think this might help you to achieve that.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293531/how-to-permanently-remove-few-commits-from-remote-branch

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to restore data depending on the infrastructure and the language that is used. Without more specific informations it is impossible to say how to fully delete the data. Anyways to override the history of a git branch you could use:

git push -f {branchName}

Answer (score 0):

Vist : https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/restoring-a-deleted-repository

To restore deleted repo you can try sending a mail to support@github.com