# Github undo or discard commits

Tags: git, github

When I type git status, I have got this message:

> Your branch is behind 'origin/mrp_v2' by 7 commits, and can be
> fast-forwarded.

How can I discard these 7 commits?

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293531/how-to-permanently-remove-few-commits-from-remote-branch

Comment: Those aren't *your* commits. You are *behind someone else's commits*. Are you sure you want to throw away *their* commits, from *their* repository?

Comment: @torek yes, I have like to discard those commits

Comment: OK, then the link @Aneesh gave is the right one: just use `git push --force` (or `--force-with-lease`). This assumes you have permission to change their repository like this, of course.