# I want to remove unneeded change from Bitbucket "my work"

Tags: git, bitbucket

I initially created a commit in the wrong repository in IntelliJ Idea.

I reverted that commit and made a commit in the correct repository.

When I did "commit and push" I didn't notice that it also created "empty push" to another repository.

Now I see that repository with none of my changes in "my work" dashboard in Bitbucket.

I have never encountered such thing before.

So there's 2 concerns:

1. Did my push somehow affect other repository/project?
2. What steps are needed to remove this changes from "my work"?

I haven't seen such thing happen in my experience and would like to be sure that my push didn't make any unnecessary side effects.

Answer (score 0):

The real question here is "does it really matter?".

1. It depends **completely** on how the repository was set up - e.g. what is your branching model, what branch did you push to, if it had any webhooks that could trigger builds on a CI server, if your organization has any audit policies and so on. Generally (if you're following some kind of [Git flow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow) and everything is set up correctly), you can only push directly to non-protected branches such as `feature/*` or `bugfix/*`, and any potentially destructive activities could be triggered only from master or release branches that are typically protected (e.g. you can't push without a PR).
2. If it really matters, please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293531/how-to-permanently-remove-few-commits-from-remote-branch/3293592#3293592) for technical details on removing the commits from remote branches. I doubt though that it is possible to remove the repository from the "My work" dashboard unless you have an open PR from the branch you pushed your commit to (which could be declined or deleted).