# Git push -f vs. +

Tags: git

What is the difference between doing:

```
 git push -f origin my-branch:my-branch
```

and

```
 git push origin +my-branch:my-branch
```

?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Those are two syntaxes for the same goal.

Except that `git push --force` can be used when you *don't* specify any refspec (meaning you want to push your current branch to a remote matching name branch).
It is easier than:

```
git push origin +yourBranch
```

, as mentioned in the [Git Community Book](http://book.git-scm.com/3_distributed_workflows.html).

See "[Why “git push helloworld +master:master” instead of just “git push helloworld”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475665/why-git-push-helloworld-mastermaster-instead-of-just-git-push-helloworld)" for illustration.