# How to reset a branch to another branch with git?

Tags: git

let's say that we have an `hotfixes` branch which was created from `master`. we added commits to `hotfixes`, but those commits were not useful, so now we want to start from a fresh copy of `master` again.

to clarify better, this is the reference workflow: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

let's also say that we pushed `hotfixes` to the `origin` remote because we have an awful set up and that's the only way to test something, so we need to reset the branch also on the remote server.

how to reset `hotfixes` to a copy of `master`?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You mean you want to push your local `master` to the remote `hotfixes` branch? Like this:

```
git push origin +master:hotfixes
```

However, this requires that you are allowed to re-write the history on the remote side.

Comment: Is this the correct syntax? When I did this I got a new remote branch with the plus (+) in the name. I had to move the plus like `git push origin +master:hotfixes`. This is according to the git spec: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push

Comment: fyi, the plus sign is shorthand for doing a `--force` during the push: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475665/why-git-push-helloworld-mastermaster-instead-of-just-git-push-helloworld

Comment: I think it's worth noting that this does not update your local (hotfixes) branch. You will still probably want to `git reset --hard origin/hotfixes` afterwards.

Comment: For future readers, I strongly suggest you take your time and understand the given command before running it to avoid a mess afterwards

Answer (score 206):

this is how i did it with basic Git commands:

```
git checkout hotfixes
git reset --hard master
git push --force origin hotfixes
```

of course it's important to notify everyone working on `hotfixes`. most likely they will have to delete their local copy and start from a fresh one. an alternative, less invasive idea is to create a new branch:

```
git checkout master
git branch -tb hotfixes-2 # this creates branch `hotfixes-2` from a copy of `master`
git push origin HEAD # this creates `hotfixes-2` on the remote server
```

Comment: Thanks for the preference, but i am curious to know why you find it less error-prone

Comment: I should have stated that it is a personal preference and wasn't trying to state a fact. 
To me, it requires more actions, which describe better what you are doing rather then just pushing to a different remote, which, in turn, makes me more aware of what I'm doing.
Also, the extra `-f` flag and `reset --hard` have warning with GUI tools like sourcetree for instance..

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that if you are using a GUI tool like source tree, then using the steps above makes you more aware, because there are warnings along the way, which means you can abort at any time..

Comment: This is the right answer. `reset --hard` shifts the local HEAD pointer for the current branch to the specified ref *and* updates the working directory tree to match it (discarding any differences).

Answer (score 13):

If I understood your question correctly, what you're looking for is a way to move the branch pointer of `origin/hotfixes` to point to the current revision of `origin/master`.

If that be the case, these set of command should work (assuming you already have checked out `hotfixes` in your local git repo any time in the past):

```
# git branch -f does not allow modifying the currently checked out
# branch, so checkout any other branch than hotfixes
git checkout <SOME_OTHER_BRANCH_THAN_HOTFIXES>

# Move the branch pointer of hotfixes to the commit currently
# pointed by origin/master
git branch -f hotfixes origin/master

# Force push the history rewrite in the hotfixes branch
# into origin
git push -f origin hotfixes
```

Comment: `Branch hotifxes set up to track remote branch master from origin.` - Not sure that's what's wanted at all

Answer (score 4):

The answers here are solid. I have needed this exact change when resetting my staging branch to master. In that case I want to both reset the origin to match master and also reset my local to match that. So here is a git alias that allows you to pass in the branch name and do both commands in one move. (It's a little dangerous)

```
reorient = "!f() { git push origin +master:$1 && git reset --hard origin/$1 ; }; f"
```

Then use it like:

```
git reorient hotfixes
```

The answers above were totally correct. But this will simply allow for fewer keystrokes and a quicker turnaround! Hope it helps.

Comment: i wouldn't wrap a `git reset --hard` in an alias so easily ... i'd be afraid to forget and lose important changes

Comment: Yeah. Like I said in the explanation "it's a little dangerous". However, in certain instances you can find yourself doing this on the regular, in which case you may want something quicker.

Comment: @danza ....then again, a `reset --hard` mistake is not unfixable. Reflog is our (dearest) friend!

Answer (score 1):

Based on a few of the answers in this thread, I did the following script with a few prompts to reduce risk of messing stuff up:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Questions for loop:
for value in {1..3}
do
  # Asking if user wants to reset hotfix:
  if [ "$value" == "1" ] ;then
    echo -n "Are you sure you want to hard reset the hotfix branch (y/n)? "
    read answer
    if [ "$answer" == "${answer#[Yy]}" ] ;then
        echo 'Okay, maybe next time.'
        exit
    fi
  fi
  # Asking if user is in void:
  if [ "$value" == "2" ] ;then
    echo -n "Are you in the void branch (y/n)? "
    read answer
    if [ "$answer" == "${answer#[Yy]}" ] ;then
        echo 'You should checkout to the void branch.'
        exit
    fi
  fi
  # Asking if user has any uncommited changes:
  if [ "$value" == "3" ] ;then
    echo -n "Do you have any uncommited changes (y/n)? "
    read answer
    if [ "$answer" == "${answer#[Nn]}" ] ;then
        echo 'You should commit your changes to avoid losing them.'
        exit
    fi
  fi
done

echo 'Resetting...'
git checkout void
git branch -f hotfix origin/master
git push -f origin hotfix
```

100% open to any feedback to improve this script.

Comment: First, not clear why you need a loop here. Second, you can check for branch/uncommitted changes yourself. The better prompt would be "You have uncommitted changes. Commit them before proceeding"

Comment: Thanks Sergei. Regarding #1, I agree, not sure why I added a loop there lol. Regarding #2, an amazing idea. I think the command is along the lines of `if [ -z "$(git status)" ];`, I'll do some digging later then improve the script.

Comment: If you want to make a tool to automate frequent git tasks, have a look at python and GitPython. Worked great for me. https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html