# git update branch from master

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

I worked on master branch, and after the project was finished I created a branch X for the specific project. Now I have changed a lot in the master branch and want to move those changes to  branch X as well.

I don't want to merge because merge would mean that changes in X would also be present after the merge right?

I want master and X to be exactly the same

Comment: So you don't need the X branch ?

Comment: Sounds like X is your release branch for project X and now you want to merge changes from master into X?

Comment: I guess, you want to rebase "X" onto the current master.

Comment: X always holds the current state of Project-X. Normally I only do little bugfixes in X. But now I have done some changes in master which I want to have in the project as well. And I want to be sure that after that, X and master holds exactly the same version of the source files.

Comment: So you want keep project-X changes AND master changes ? If yes, you should use merge or rebase.

Comment: @dustinmoris exactly, but I want to update all files in X from the master branch. So no classic merging

Comment: @jedema no I want to overwrite X with master

Comment: So, during each merges you want to keep the master version ?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173919/is-there-a-theirs-version-of-git-merge-s-ours

Comment: You can rename branches.

Comment: Any answer actually answered your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you want merge master and X-project branch by keeping only master version when conflicts raise you must use the **theirs** merge strategy :

```
# checkout out in X project branch and
git merge -s theirs master
```

You'll find more detail in the documentation of merge : http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge

Answer (score 0):

If you want `master` and `X` to be exactly the same and thereby drop all changes you made on `X` the easiest way would be to delete `X` and create a new one.

```
git checkout master
# the big 'D' means you want to delete an unmerged branch
git branch -D X
# create a new 'X'
git branch X
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15943471/2418066.

For your case you should execute this:

```
git push origin +master:X
```