# Why "git push" is rejected? ("git pull" doesn't help)

Tags: git, git-push

My current branch is `my_branch`. Trying to push the changes to the remote repo I get:

```
$ git push
Counting objects: 544, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (465/465), done.
Writing objects: 100% (533/533), 2.04 MiB | 1.16 MiB/s, done.
Total 533 (delta 407), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@......git
   4ed90a6..52673f3  my_branch -> my_branch
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@......git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

Trying to `git pull` results in:

```
$ git pull
Already up-to-date.
```

Why I get this error?
How could I resolve this problem and perform `git push` successfully?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> My current branch is my_branch.

That is your problem. When you pull, Git is telling you that your branch `my_branch` is up to date, *not* `master`, which is behind `origin/master` making a fast-forward merge impossible.

In order to push master, you need to check out `master` and pull. This will merge in the changes waiting on `origin/master` and allow you to push your own changes.

```
git checkout master
git pull
# resolve conflicts, if any
git push
```

Comment: If you only want to push "my_branch": git push origin my_branch.

Comment: Just to clarify the accepted answer some: `4ed90a6..52673f3  my_branch -> my_branch` indicates that `my_branch` has been updated successfully, but `! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)` indicates that the master branch has failed. This means that *some refs* have failed to be pushed to the repository, but some others *may* have gone through ok, like `my_branch`.

Comment: This also can happen if you host the git repository by yourself and you are remotely checked (and logged in via terminal for example) into the remote branch you would like to push. In that case switch branch (on remote) and push again.

Answer (score 11):

[If your master branch is already configured to rebase on pull, then you just need to do a pull on the master branch as is described in other answerd, but otherwise:]

If you get a non-fast-forward message, this means you can only push commits on top of the existing commits, but you're trying to do otherwise. Do a rebase on master before pushing (assuming the remote is called origin):

```
git checkout master
git pull --rebase origin master
git push
```

See also this question: [git rebase and git push: non-fast forward, why use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559917/git-rebase-and-git-push-non-fast-forward-why-use)

Answer (score 4):

change developer permission to "Maintainer"

Comment: Isn't it a comment quality answer.

Answer (score 3):

**It could also be a Git Hook!**
That would give the same error.

Git Hooks run locally, so they can intercept and "pre-process" your commits before they are pushed.

More on Git Hooks here: https://githooks.com/
You should be able to find the hooks in the root of your repo, here: `.git/hooks`.
Reading through the hook files may or may not not be helpful; they are full of advanced git commands and regexp.
Use File Explorer/Finder to look, as files prefixed by a period (.git, .gitignore) are often hidden in IDE's.

I got this same error when trying to push a branch called `feature/JIRA-123_description-text`, and after some looking around I discovered that all the other project branches were named `features/...`, so I was just missing an **s** in the word features. Renaming the branch fixed it.

So, in case pulling master etc does not fix the issue, try looking at some other branch names and match the format. Or check docs to see if there are special branch naming policies, or if you've tried to push something in the wrong file format et cetera.

Answer (score 2):

what solved it for me:

go to https://github.com/settings/emails

unckeck: "Block command line pushes that expose my email"

the issue for me was: I had my email in the license

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the exact branch to pull using

```bash
git pull some_origin some_branch
```

might help. I was on `some_branch`, and `git pull` without the extra info wouldn't pull `some_branch`, although it was checked out. Without having pulled correctly, a `git push` was naturally rejected.

However, this is not intended behavior. The likely cause was an unconventional git [configuration](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/dotfiles) for dot files, with the work tree and git directory separated.