# git rebase causes origin/master and master to diverge

Tags: git, push, rebase

I've already looked at questions

[git rebase and git push: non-fast forward, why use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559917/git-rebase-and-git-push-non-fast-forward-why-use)

and

[master branch and 'origin/master' have diverged, how to 'undiverge' branches'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452226/master-branch-and-origin-master-have-diverged-how-to-undiverge-branches)

I'm still not clear on what I need to do in this specific case. I had origin/master and master in sync first. The sequence of commits on both is

```
---o---A---B
```

I now commit two more commits on my local repository so that I have

```
---o---A---B---C---D
```

Now I did a rebase because I wanted to reorder the commits. So my master is now :-

```
---o---A---C---D---B
```

while my origin/master is still as it was in the first situation. Now, if I try to do a git push, it refuses to push it because master and origin/master have diverged. How do I push this rebase to origin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force it with:

```
git push -f origin master
```

Be careful though. This is actually changing the history on origin, so only do this if you know it won't break anything for other devs, for example.

In general it's not a good idea to rebase commits that have already been pushed to a remote/central repository.

Comment: Hmmm. Would it be safer/easier if I pushed my changes in state 2 to the origin then ssh-ed to the remote machine and did the rebase in the remote repository and then did a git pull on my local machine? Or is this strictly worse that what I'm trying to do?

Comment: @owagh, that's a roundabout method for the same effect and has the same problem -- changing history on the remote repo could cause problems for other developers using it.

Comment: Ohk. Lemme try it out and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this several times and at first I pulled like git said, which would try to merge my past changes with my new local changes -not okay. Basically, when your local repo branch has diverged from your remote branch, you must rebase your remote branch as well. E.g.:

```
git:(branch)$ git commit -m "my fix."
git:(branch)$ git checkout master
git:(master)$ git rebase branch
git:(master)$ git rebase origin/master
git:(master)$ git push origin master
```

great success!