# Update a fork with new commits on its master branch?

Tags: git, version-control

I forked branch A and created B. Now, A has been updated by others and I'd like to bring those commits over to my B fork, so I can ensure the stuff I've been doing there still works with that new A content.

How can I do this? Git's terminology (pull, fetch, merge, etc.) is hugely unintuitive, at least early on :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise (if none has already pulled from B):

What you have is a Branch `A` with new evolution and possible commits done in the **[upstream repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749166/6309)**:

```
        a--a--a (origin/A)
       /
a--a--a A
 \
  b--b--b (B, local branch)
```

First make sure `A` is up-to-date with the upstream repo content: `origin/A`:

```
git checkout A
git pull
```

That will give you:

```
a--a--a--a--a--a (A, origin/A)
 \
  b--b--b (B, local branch)
```

Then You would rebase your local modifications done on `B` on top of `A` (I suppose here that [`A` has an upstream branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6244487/6309), meaning [it does track `origin/A`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2286030/6309), which you can check with `git branch -avvv`)

```
git checkout B
git rebase A
```

Which gives you:

```
a--a--a--a--a--a (A, origin/A)
                \
                 b'--b'--b' (B, local branch)
```

Note that changes the history of `B`, so if `B` was already pushed, you would have to `push --force origin B`, which can be dangerous if others already started working on `B`.
See (for more on the rebase tricks):

- "[Git push rejected after feature branch rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8940299/6309)"
- "[`git rebase` and `git push`: non-fast forward, why use?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/559971/6309)"

---

Note: "fork a branch" isn't the recommended expression, since fork is more commonly used to refer to a cloned repo on the server side: see "[Git fork is git clone?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6286877/6309)".

Instead, you would say: "I branched `A` and created `B`": the operation is "branching" (*not* "forking").

Comment: Won't that rebase modify A?

Comment: @lukech the rebase **will not** modify A, it will recreate B on top of A.

Comment: @lukech I have added a few schema to better explain the nature of the rebase operation.

Comment: @lukech note, avoid the term 'fork' when making a new branch; It is simply called "branching". A fork is reserved for a cloned repo on the server side: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6286877/6309

Comment: See what I was saying about the terminology being confusing? :)